# Is eyebrow threading permissible if it's done for oneself, and not to show off?

Tags: women, hijab, hair

Nowadays, women and girls have shape their eyebrows, such as through [eyebrow threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threading_(epilation)) (which may extend to the full face).  My opinion is that most of them do it just to show off.

However, if this activity is just for oneself, and not for showing off, such as inside the house and while observing hijab, is it allowed in Islam?

Comment: making eyebrows means making shape of eyebrows by removing extra hairs and threading of full face also means removing hairs from face using thread or other equipments.

Comment: The action itself is condemned, not the intent of the person. Plus, what does "for yourself" mean? Nothing! People already dress half-naked and say they do it for "themselves" and not people. It's just an excuse.

Comment: I suggest that you seek a specific *fatwa* as what you are asking about will depend on what you mean by *hijāb*, and whether you are married, and which madhhab you are asking about, etc. (see this [*fatwa*](https://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=175407), Arabic only).